# Is there any other way to set a dict value using python?

Tags: python, dictionary

This is my code:

```
a={}
a['b']=0
print a['b']
```

And this is my other code (**that is wrong**):

```
a={}
a.b=0
print a.b
```

Is there any other way to set the value associated with a key in a python `dict`?

Comment: i want to use a method like get, a.get('b',0),  so  a.set('b',0)

Comment: Are you having trouble reading this?  http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = {'b':0}
```

or

```
a = dict([('b',0)])
```

or

```
a = dict.fromkeys(['b'], 0)
```

or

```
a = {}
b = {'b':0}
a.update(b)
```

or

```
a = {}
a.__setitem__('b',0)
```